# Does gcc cache the address of a global array at a static index by default?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

Let's say I have the global array
`char global_array[3] = {33, 17, 6};` and I access `global_array[1]`. When gcc interprets `global_array[1]`, will it add 1 to the address of `global_array` at runtime, or change `global_array[1]` to a static address, assuming -O0? If not, is there a compiler flag to for gcc to make the static index of an array a static pointer?

Comment: I doubt any compiler provides any guarantees about the way it optimizes the code. Why does it matter to you? Are you going after performance or something else?

Comment: Good news: [this happens](https://godbolt.org/z/PMTWznYMj). `[rip+some_offset]` is sort of an addition, but not in the way you meant it.

Comment: I know from experience that the Atmel port of gcc does the optimization at -02. But that optimization may be specific to that target.

Comment: @harold good finding! I wonder if that "addition" embedded in the opcode is slower than a fixed address... I think so.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica maybe, but there is no choice anyway, a 32-bit fixed address is not an option for x64 (at least not under normal circumstances) and a 64-bit fixed address is not encodeable (except in a couple of special cases)

Comment: Indeed, x86 is the only popular architecture that supports this. arm32, arm64, mips, riscv, powerpc, none of them support pointer-sized immediates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When gcc interprets global_array[1], will it add 1 to the address of global_array at runtime, or change global_array[1] to a static address, assuming `-O0`?

There's no particular guarantees of what gcc does and does not depending on level of optimization. Take your example under gcc 12.2 for x86_64:

```c
int func (void)
{
  char global_array[3] = {33, 17, 6};

  return global_array[1];
}
```

This results in peculiar assembly code under `-O0`:

```
func:

  push    rbp
  mov     rbp, rsp
  mov     WORD PTR [rbp-3], 4385
  mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], 6
  movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-2]
  movsx   eax, al
  pop     rbp
  ret
```

It is storing the array of the stack but it loads the magic number 4385 as a word, then loads a 6 at the end. Now wth is 4385? It is 0x1121 hex. Where the bytes have values 0x11 = 17dec and 0x21 = 33, and since it is a x86 little endian, the byte order for the `WORD` instruction is reversed vs the order of the array.

This word write is already some manner of mini-optimization even though I used `-O0`. So again - no guarantees. Regarding your question, the access part `rbp-2` is indeed similar to adding 1 the to the address in runtime. In this case it is subtracting an offset from the stack frame pointer, but that's essentially the same thing (and likely as fast/slow as adding 1 to an address).

The normal thing when optimizations are enabled would otherwise be to replace the whole thing with the absolute value.

> If not, is there a compiler flag to for gcc to make the static index of an array a static pointer?

Messing around with compiler options is probably not how. If you wish to have a pointer to a fixed address, then this is the usual steps:

- Create a custom segment at a fixed address in the linker script for the specific target.
- Declare your array at file scope and use gcc variable attributes to allocate it inside your custom segment.
- Now `&global_array[1]` is always the same address.